# Insert data to DB2 table with autoincrement ID without defining column list

Tags: db2

I have a DB2 table named TEST where the ID is autoincremented starting from 1.
Columns are ID, col1, col2, col3.
When I want to insert manually like this:

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1, 2, 3).
```

It throws an error that the number of columns in the table are not in line with the number of values I want to insert.
Then I need to specify the column list in the insert statement for this to work:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3)
```

I there any other way to insert the data without specifying the column list? Similar to the first version.

Comment: There is no way to make the first version any more workable than the second version already is.  Use the second version, and it is best practice to _always_ list out the explicit target columns.

Comment: noted, thank you

Comment: I agree with Tim. If someone adds or removes columns to this table later, your statement without explicit target column names fails.

Comment: It's a really bad practice to exclude the column list. If the table is altered later -- by adding, altering, or removing columns -- the INSERT query will become unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: It's a really bad practice to exclude the column list.